# Wordpress login redirect not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I made some changes to my Wordpress.org URL settings. Now I can't login to my Website using the /wp-login.php link. First of all the theme is not loading which is the first odd thing. After I type in the correct credits and I press login I get redirectet to my domain but the last letter of the top-level-domain is missing. Maybe I forgot deleted it in the edit proccess or something else went wrong. I have access to a terminal but I don't know which file to edit.

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: My guess is a typo when saving your settings. Use something like Sequel Pro or phpMyAdmin to access the database and look at the `wp_options` table under `siteurl` and `home`. If you can get into more specifics about what you changed it would help.

Answer (score 0):

This recently happened to me too.  After looking at .htaccess and (as @tom-woodward mentions on his comment) verifying wp_options table values, I ended up fixing by changing DNS provider (GoDaddy to Cloudflare).  Apparently there was a weird glitch with Godaddy DNS servers.  Let me know if this fixes yours too.